# Elasticsearch 2.0.0 security manager with groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, elasticsearch

I'm using brand new Elasticsearch 2.0.0 from a Java application.

When calling the `prepareUpdate()` method with an inline groovy script that has the following code:

```
import org.elasticsearch.common.logging.*
import groovy.json.*

ESLogger logger = ESLoggerFactory.getLogger('events-sequence.groovy')

def TOKEN_SEPARATOR = "###"
def flow = [ ]

try {
    ctx._source.events.reverseEach { e ->
        def context = e.tuplenized_context ? JsonOutput.toJson(e.tuplenized_context) : "[]"
        flow << (e.name.toLowerCase() + TOKEN_SEPARATOR + context.toLowerCase())
    }
    ctx._source.flow = flow.join(TOKEN_SEPARATOR)

} catch (Throwable t) {
    logger.error("Error applying derivation", t)
    throw t
}
```

I'm receiving the following exception:

```
    java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "groovy.json.faststringutils.write.to.final.fields" "read")
```

According to the stacktrace, this happens when calling the `JsonOutput.toJson()` method:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at groovy.json.internal.CharBuf.addJsonFieldName(CharBuf.java:516)
        at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:423)
        at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:267)
        at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeIterator(JsonOutput.java:441)
        at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:269)
        at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.java:187)
        at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at 3974cbb354b454f7c665982a3a8f854ede6125fb$_run_closure1.doCall(3974cbb354b454f7c665982a3a8f854ede6125fb:18)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:442)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2030)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.reverseEach(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2172)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$532.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at 3974cbb354b454f7c665982a3a8f854ede6125fb.run(3974cbb354b454f7c665982a3a8f854ede6125fb:17)
        at org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:248)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.executeScript(UpdateHelper.java:251)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:196)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:79)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardUpdateOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:408)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:203)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase.performOnPrimary(TransportReplicationAction.java:579)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase$1.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:452)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "groovy.json.faststringutils.write.to.final.fields" "read")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1294)
        at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:753)
        at groovy.json.internal.FastStringUtils.<clinit>(FastStringUtils.java:37)
        ... 42 more
```

In my `elasticsearch.yml` config file, I've added these 2 lines:

```
script.inline: on 
script.indexed: on
```

Is there anything else I need to configure so that I can serialize an object to JSON within a groovy script?

**EDIT:** I've also tried to initialize Elasticsearch setting the following option:

```
export ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Dgroovy.json.faststringutils.write.to.final.fields\=true
```

But had no luck, since the problem seems to be that there are no permissions to access the `groovy.json.faststringutils.write.to.final.fields` system property, whatever its value is.

---

**EDIT 2:** All modifying the default `java.policy` file, specifying a new policy file with the `-Djava.security.manager` and `-Djava.security.policy=file:///my.policy` options and disabling the security manager via the `-Dsecurity.manager.enabled=false` option didn't work.

I've reported this as an issue to the Elasticsearch guys, and they've already fixed it. Actually, [here's the commit](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/14500/files), but it won't be available until version 2.1.

Is there any workaround or configuration option to make it work now?

Comment: Strange, I am on 2.0.0 and I also had problem with JsonOutput, but it was reported differently (Just ClsDefNotFound error). The root cause in my case wasn't the property read, but the [usage](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/internal/FastStringUtils.java#L21) of sun.misc.Unsafe in the FastStringUtils class. In my case disabling the security manager for elasticsearch with `-Dsecurity.manager.enabled=false` fixed this problem

Answer (score 2):

None of the other suggestions here worked for me either, but I did find that I could disable the ES security manager by adding the following to my elasticsearch.yml file...

```
security.manager.enabled: false
```

Note that this is deprecated as of 2.2.0 and will likely be removed soon. This is not a best practice and should be avoided when dynamic scripts are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update your [policy file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) with the system property read permission.

Add: `permission java.util.PropertyPermission "groovy.json.faststringutils.write.to.final.fields", "read"` to the `grant` block.

The default policy file (`java.policy`) resides under `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security`, unless specified otherwise using `java.security.policy` system property.

Alternatively, run the JVM without a security manager with `-Dsecurity.manager.enabled=false`

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work, neither modifying the `java.policy` file nor disabling the security manager via the `-Dsecurity.manager.enabled=false` option.

Answer (score 0):

A better way of implementing it is to define your script under /config/scripts. As your script is static, you gain following advantages out of it:

1. No inline scripting required which makes your application safe.
2. Script is compiled once and used again. This gives you performance gain.
3. No need to change any java security policy.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm working in a cloud environment, though. I don't want to complicate deploy of the application by taking care of the scripts, which would need to be deployed to the elasticsearch cluster separately, and this would happen if I'd take this approach.